# Как делать инициализацию(загружать все необходимые данные) react-native приложения после авторизации?

Tags: react-native

Пишу приложение и понял что надо загружать данные/информацию в каком-то одном месте.
Сейчас нужные данные загружаются в каждом отдельном экране.
как и где делать первичную инициализацию приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единого ответа быть не может, все зависит от архитектуры вашего проекта и используемых библиотек. Как я понимаю вам необходимо выделить сетевой слой и внутреннее хранилище данных и логику по управлению запросами (предоставлять данные из хранилища и следить за их обновлением, повторно запрашивать и т.п).

Я использую следующий стек библиотек: 
хранение данных, шина событий и т.п. – redux,
сетевой слой - https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce (на основе axios),
комплексная бизнес-логика, связка с сетью –  redux-saga

Для инициализации приложения можно сделать "экран загрузки" в котором вы подготовите данные (сделаете все необходимые запросы) и после этого покажите что-то полезное пользователю или замените этот экран другим.